# Unrecognized option 'hls_segment_size'

Tags: ffmpeg, centos, http-live-streaming

I am using CentOS and I want to convert mp4 to HLS(m3u8 files). I got this error : 
Unrecognized option 'hls_segment_size' , when I want to execute this command :

```
     ffmpeg -i testffm.mp4 -b:v 1M -g 60 -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_size 500000 exist.m3u8
```

what can I do? I need to define hls_segment_size...

Comment: not a programming question

Comment: There's no such option.

Comment: @Mulvya yes there is, but it's not in the docs. See `libavformat/hlsenc.c`. Probably old `ffmpeg`.

Comment: So there is.Wonder how many AVOptions are undocumented.

Comment: @Mulvya It should be relatively easy to make a parser that matches against the `*.texi`. I'll try it the next time I get bored :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your ffmpeg does not support HLS?

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -formats|grep hls
```

Comment: Not the case. Had it been so, parsing would have failed at `-hls_time 2`

Comment: The answer is configuration with below option.
'--enable-muxer=segment
 --enable-muxer=stream_segment'
for more detail.
Please refer [ffmpeg document](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment)

Comment: @Mulvya For the condition. '--enable-muxer=hls' will be right configuration.
Please check with ffmpeg full help **ffmpeg -h full**, and then read carefully

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The OP's build had hls muxer enabled, but it was before the option `-hls_segment_size` was added. Nothing to do with the generic (s)segment muxer.